# PyEphem -- satellites with a lunar orbit?

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

I'm trying to figure out the position of the moon given an observer in a lunar orbit. I have searched the internet already, but cannot find if PyEphem has this capability. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyEphem does not, alas, have that capability.